# Isotope Pagination with load more

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-pagination

I used the isotope from the site http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ and implemented a method to use load more items by pressing a button. 
The problem is that when i hide the elements to display only the initial number of elements, my isotope grid won't scale. If i press the show more button, the layout accurately scales.

It seems that

```
  $grid.isotope('hideItemElements', $(this)).isotope('layout');
```

but

```
 $grid.isotope('revealItemElements', $(this)).isotope('layout');
```

works just fine. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Here is a demo in codepan: http://codepen.io/laura-chesches/pen/RKPWGo

Answer (score 6):

I managed to resolve my own problem and make a functional load more (show more) button.
Here is the working code:

http://codepen.io/laura-chesches/pen/xgEOpY

It seems that i shouldn't have used arrangeComplete event, i just needed to create a new function in which i used:

```
 var itemElems = $grid.isotope('getFilteredItemElements');
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
This seems like such a simple problem to solve but has been driving me crazy for far too long...  this is perfect for what I need!